# How to make Spotify Snap Open Shared Song URLs?

Tags: snap, spotify, xdg

**Expectation:**

With the Spotify snap on Ubuntu, I would like Spotify to open a specific song when clicking on a link shared.

**What happens:**

My browser opens with the popup: `Allow this site to open the spotify link with the System Handler?`

When clicking `Open Link`, the Spotify desktop application opens, but the shared song isn't navigated to within Spotify.

**Version Info**

OS: Lunar / Gnome

Spotify: Spotify version 1.2.11.916.geb595a67, Copyright (c) 2023, Spotify Ltd